# force the browser to remember options on a selection box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Right now i'm using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#submit-car').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var brand = $('#brand option:selected').text();
            var model = $('#model option:selected').text();
            var size = $('#size option:selected').text();
            location.href ='index.php?s='+brand+'+'+model+'+'+size+'';
        });
});
```

to send some variables to the url. I would like to know if there is a way to force the browser to remember what values were selected by the site visitor after they go to the new url.

Comment: This is why cookies were invented..

Comment: You can use cookies or local storage.

Answer (score 0):

Use sessions (saved on the server) or cookies (saved on the clients pc).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use some php coding to set [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) when the user clicks to go to the next url.  For example:

```
<?php
  setcookie("Brand", "brand_value", time()+3600); // Expires in one hour
 ?>
```

Then on the next page you can retrieve Brand, like this:

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE["Brand"]; ?> // echoes the value of Brand
```

**In more detail** you could try this:

**Main_File**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-car').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var brand = $('#brand option:selected').text();
        var model = $('#model option:selected').text();
        var size = $('#size option:selected').text();
        // Ajax call to a cookies.php file, passing the values
        $.get('cookies.php', { thebrand: brand, themodel: model, thesize: size },
        function() {
          // When the call has been completed, open next page
          location.href ='index.php?s='+brand+'+'+model+'+'+size+'';
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

**cookies.php**

```
<?php

if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {

    // Get all the values
    $theBrand = $_GET["thebrand"];
    $theModel = $_GET["themodel"];
    $theSize = $_GET["thesize"];

    // Call the setTheCookies function, below
    setTheCookies($theBrand, $theModel, $theSize);

    // The setTheCookies function
    function setTheCookies($theBrand, $theModel, $theSize)
    {
        setcookie("Brand", $theBrand, time()+3600);
        setcookie("Model", $theModel, time()+3600);
        setcookie("Size", $theSize, time()+3600);
    }
}

?>
```

**Next Page**

```
<?php

  // Get all the values from the next page
  $getBrand = $_COOKIE["Brand"];
  $getModel = $_COOKIE["Model"];
  $getSize = $_COOKIE["Size"];

?>
```